# additional http header not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, http-headers, httpurlconnection, httpconnection

I'm trying to add headers into http and below in my code -

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/share/page"); 
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("SsoUserHeader", "admin"); 
conn.addRequestProperty("mysso", "hi");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization",basicAuth );
conn.connect();

Map<String, List<String>> hdrs = conn.getHeaderFields();
Set<String> hdrKeys = hdrs.keySet();
for (String k : hdrKeys)
    System.out.println("Key: " + k + "  Value: " + hdrs.get(k));

System.out.println("Header1: "+conn.getHeaderField("SsoUserHeader"));
System.out.println("Header2: "+conn.getHeaderField("mysso"));
System.out.println("Header3: "+conn.getHeaderField("Authorization"));
```

But when I'm trying to print the values of those headers then it is coming as null. Please let me know how to get the header value. Output I'm getting

```
Key: null  Value: [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
Key: Content-Language  Value: [en-US]
Key: Transfer-Encoding  Value: [chunked]
Key: Date  Value: [Sun, 07 Jul 2013 05:30:45 GMT]
Key: Set-Cookie  Value: [JSESSIONID=E6BCB7632619ABF41D1A7C6D7CDC53E4;  
                                Path=/share/; HttpOnly]

Key: Content-Type  Value: [text/html;charset=utf-8]
Key: Server  Value: [Apache-Coyote/1.1]
Key: Cache-Control  Value: [no-cache]

Header1: null
Header2: null
Header3: null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getHeaderFields()` returns header fields that were sent in the HTTP response, not in the HTTP request. You never sent these headers: Content-Language, Transfer-Encoding, etc. and yet you get them in getHeaderFields(). This is because the server sent these headers. 
The custom header fields set in the request will be available to **`http://localhost:8080/share/page`**

/page can access these header fields using:

```
request.getHeader("SsoUserHeader"); //admin
request.getHeader("mysso"); //hi
request.getHeader("Authorization");
```